# Match python pyfits table by column

Tags: python, numpy, fits

I am trying to match two `pyfits` data objects by a OBJNO (object number) column.  In IDL this is done with the `match, A.objno, B.objno, ii, jj` procedure.  This returns two indicies `ii` and `jj` which index `A` and `B` such that `A[ii].objno == B[ii].objno`.

Is there a numpy/pythonic way of doing this? I would not like to make any stipulations on the ordering or size of either `A` or `B` since they may be large fits tables.  This is what I am doing now:

```
ii = np.in1d(A.OBJNO, B.OBJNO).nonzero()[0]
jj = [np.where(B.OBJNO == objno)[0][0] for objno in A[ii].field('OBJNO')]
```

Is there a better numpy array matching algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Denoting the sizes of your arrays `N` and `M` (`N > M`), your solution is O(N*M).

Assuming your arrays are large enough, you'll be better off with a O(N*logN) solution.  You can achieve that by first sorting the bigger array (call is `A`), and then performing a binary search (e.g. using `bisect`) of each element from `B` in `sorted_A`.